# Word "index" is handled weirdly by Apache's mod_rewrite. Why?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Hellp everyone.

I have such an .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 # Modify the RewriteBase if rewrite rules are not working properly.
 RewriteBase /

 RedirectMatch 404 /(php\.ini|core\.php|config\.php|modules)(/|$)


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

When I try to use URLs such as "index/desktop" I've got nothing in PHP $_REQUEST array, but after changing this URL to "desktop" everything works correctly.

I suppose that this behaviour is connected with index.php rule, but don't have clear understanding of what's happening.

Comment: the word index is fine, is the expected behaviour for you tobe doing this `index.php?q=index/desktop`? or `index.php?q=desktop`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

above

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) option.